# Using cURL with PHP to store files in an object storage service by OpenStack

Tags: php, curl, openstack

So basically I am using AngularJS to upload a file to the webserver then attempting to store it in my **public** object store in OpenStack.

For now my attempt at getting the file to the webserver and more specifically to a local folder called uploads.

However even though there are no execution errors on curl_exec (I am not sure how to get the Response code..), it doesn't seem to be uploaded at all.

Here is my code for reference::
(I am new to PHP please spare me!)

```
include_once "config.php";    
$target_dir = "./upload/";
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "I am here";
print_r($_FILES);
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
print_r($target_file);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
    echo "Upload";
}
else{
    echo "couldn't upload!";
}
print_r($file_name_with_full_path); 
    //write code for saving to object store 

$target_url = 'http://myobjectstore' + $name;
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.6+   
    $cFile = curl_file_create($target_file); 
} 
else { //   
    $cFile = '@' . realpath($target_file); 
} 
$data = array('file_contents'=> $cFile); 
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
if($result == true){
    echo "File posted";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR: " . curl_error($ch);
}
```